# SSL and ProxyPass

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, node.js

js server running on `8200` and I just got some SSL certificates for my domain. I want to be able to serve my page over HTTPS.

So far my apache config file is like so

File: /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/synsis.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerAdmin sova.k@gmail.com
  ServerName  www.synsis.live
  ServerAlias synsis.live

  SSLEngine On
  SSLProxyEngine On
  SSLCertificateFile "/home/vas/synsis.live/certs/domain.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "/home/vas/synsis.live/certs/domain.key"
  SSLCertificateChainFile "/home/vas/synsis.live/certs/intermediate.pem"


  ProxyRequests Off
  <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>

<Location />
  ProxyPass  https://localhost:8200/
  ProxyPassReverse  https://localhost:8200/
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

However, my site does not load using this config.  Any ideas?

`apachectl -t`

```
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Syntax OK
```

and 
`apachectl -S`

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server 127.0.1.1 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost 127.0.1.1 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost ch.mu (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/c.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost www.hai.run (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/hai.conf:3)
                 alias hai.run
         port 80 namevhost practicalhuman.org (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ph.conf:4)
                 alias www.practicalhuman.org
*:443                  www.synthesis.live (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/synthesis.conf:5)

ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
Mutex proxy: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/lock/apache2" mechanism=fcntl
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
Group: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
```

Comment: output of `apachectl -t` please

Comment: -t and -S posted up top.

Comment: is your backend ssl?

Answer (score 2):

You configuration contains three of my major gripes about configuration examples out there *in the wild*

1. The use of `<Proxy *>` blocks when configuring an reverse proxy. `<Proxy>` blocks are *almost* exclusively used to configure forward proxies not reverse. In your case it is not needed.
2. The use of `ProxyPass` inside location blocks. Best practise is to use the 2 argument version of `ProxyPass` unless there is no alternative.
3. Use of Apache v2.2 authorisation directives in Apache v2.4. I would strongly recommend *always* changing all your v2.2 `Allow`, `Order`, `Satisfy` and `require` directives to the new v2.4 `Require` directive and `<RequireAny>` and `<RequireAll>` blocks.
4. The `SSLProxyEngine` directive is used to configure your server when you are proxying *to* and SSL based service and has nothing to do with whether your actual virtual host is an SSL one or not (Yes I know I said 3, but this is a very minor one, and I only added it because you replied saying your back-end was not SSL enabled :-)

Try the following as a base, and hopefully "clean", configuration and work from there. *f it doesn't work, tell us what actually happens rather than just saying "it doesn't work".

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerAdmin sova.k@gmail.com
  ServerName  www.synsis.live
  ServerAlias synsis.live

  SSLEngine On
  SSLProxyEngine On
  SSLCertificateFile "/home/vas/synsis.live/certs/domain.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "/home/vas/synsis.live/certs/domain.key"
  SSLCertificateChainFile "/home/vas/synsis.live/certs/intermediate.pem"

  # This is the default anyway, but no harm having it explicitly set
  ProxyRequests Off

  # You say in a comment your backend is not SSL, but your original configuration
  # tries to proxy to an SSL enabled service. This is almost certainly
  # why it originally failed
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8200/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8200/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: The only things that work are:  Setting the VirtualHost line to `VirtualHost *:80` instead of 443; with the port set to 443 it never connects, but just drops back onto my root site on the same ip.  I want to be able to access the site at `https://mysite.whatever` .. I've tried setting the `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` lines to read `https://~~` instead and still it either just times out or drops back to my root site for the same IP.  Is there an "ordering" of sites being served by apache that may have something to do with it?

Comment: You are mixing up several concepts. The `ProxyPass` lines need to match the protocol of your back-end server, the `<VirtualHost>` definition needs to match how you wish to access your vhost with your browser. By *Dropping back to your root site* means you are just hitting your default vhost because Apache has not matched the Host header to another vhost.

Comment: ah okay thanks for the clarification.  I'm going to make my node.Js backend use SSL and see how it goes from there.  Thanks for your help thus far

Answer (score 0):

is your backend ssl?

**if not:**

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerAdmin sova.k@gmail.com
  ServerName  www.synsis.live
  ServerAlias synsis.live

  SSLEngine On
  SSLProxyEngine On
  SSLCertificateFile "/home/vas/synsis.live/certs/domain.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "/home/vas/synsis.live/certs/domain.key"
  SSLCertificateChainFile "/home/vas/synsis.live/certs/intermediate.pem"


  ProxyRequests Off
  <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>

<Location />
  ProxyPass  http://localhost:8200/
  ProxyPassReverse  http://localhost:8200/
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

**if it is:**

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerAdmin sova.k@gmail.com
  ServerName  www.synsis.live
  ServerAlias synsis.live

  SSLEngine On
  SSLProxyEngine On
  SSLCertificateFile "/home/vas/synsis.live/certs/domain.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "/home/vas/synsis.live/certs/domain.key"
  SSLCertificateChainFile "/home/vas/synsis.live/certs/intermediate.pem"


  ProxyRequests Off
  <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>

<Location />
  SSLProxyEngine on
  ProxyPass  https://localhost:8200/
  ProxyPassReverse  https://localhost:8200/
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, My backend is not SSL currently.  Using node.js.  Still no dice...  I'm going to try using nginx